# stringContainsInAnyOrder matcher in Hamcrest?

Tags: java, hamcrest

There's a [StringContainsInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/text/StringContainsInOrder.html) Matcher in Hamcrest.

How can I assert that a String contains a collection of Strings in any order?

Comment: can the elements in the String be easily split? i.e. is there any separator?

Comment: @Ruben unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine multiple `contains` matcher.

```
assertThat("this is a string", allOf(
  contains("string"),
  contains("this"),
  contains("a")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because of the way how Hamcrest checks the collection.

It is iterating over it, look here:
https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/text/StringContainsInOrder.java?r=375

You could:

1) test each order if it is short String (not effective)

2) sort and test few times, believing that it will cover more than 90% cases (not adequate)

Hope it helps.